# Check if is post type archive and in category

Tags: custom-post-type-archives

I'm trying to adjust a function that checks if the site visitor is on a post type archive and returns a certain layout. I need it to also check to see if it is in certain categories (using regular WP categories - not custom taxonomies).

This is the original code that works.

```
// ADD ARCHIVE LAYOUT FOR POSITION VIDEOS POST TYPE
function custom_filter_positionvids_layout( $layout_id ) {
if ( is_post_type_archive('position_video') )
        return '58bef4ba370de';

return $layout_id;
}
add_filter( 'builder_filter_current_layout', 'custom_filter_positionvids_layout' );
```

Can I add some sort of && statement with category ID's so it will check if the page is displaying the post type archive and in a list of certain categories? This will help me give a different layout for protected member content.

Answer (score 1):

You would just need to add your `else if` checks as needed. Category archives can be detected using [`is_tax( $taxonomy, $term )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/) or more specifically [`is_category( $term_id|$term_name )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/).

```
// ADD ARCHIVE LAYOUT FOR POSITION VIDEOS POST TYPE
function custom_filter_positionvids_layout( $layout_id ) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'position_video' ) ) {
        return '58bef4ba370de';
    }

    if ( is_category( 'blog' ) ) {
        return '12345';
    }

    if ( is_category( 5 ) ) {
        return '54321';
    }

    return $layout_id;
}
add_filter( 'builder_filter_current_layout', 'custom_filter_positionvids_layout' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AND operator `&&`, you can retrieve the category by different parameters [see codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) for reference

```
function custom_filter_positionvids_layout( $layout_id ) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'position_video' ) && is_category( array('category1_id', 'category2_id') ) ) {
        return '58bef4ba370de';
    }

    return $layout_id;
}
add_filter( 'builder_filter_current_layout', 'custom_filter_positionvids_layout' );
```